# Hover state for outer element counted via inner frame

Tags: html, css

When there is an outer element with border and inner element inside, is it possible to make hover effect for border of outer element only when cursor inside borders?

So for example, when i create such markup:

```
<div class="b mn">
    <p><a href="#"><img src=""></a></p>
</div>
```

```
/*...*/
div.b.mn p{
 margin: 4px 4px 5px 4px;
 border: 2px dashed #93F;
 background-clip: content-box;
}
div.b.mn p:hover, div.b.mn p:focus{
 border-color: #F93;
}
```

Hovering effect (border-color change) sticked to the outer element, so border highlights even when cursor exactly on the border, but i need somehow to highlight outer border only when inner element gets hovered by cursor.

[image: Hovering problem]

-> Link to full jsFiddle: [demo markup](https://jsfiddle.net/Markus_13/p62Lrhsk/)

I know how to do such effect via jQuery or pure JavaScript, but i wonder if there r plain html/css solution. It may be a different approach to same concept, i don't mind that as long as it fits into pure markup paradigm.

P.S. I will gratefully appreciate any other suggestions or pointed out mistakes i have among my html/css-code in my jsFiddlet. Because i have feeling that i overcomplicated things for such a simple layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `hover` to `a` not `p` and make it `display:inline-block;` to cover the border as block level element.

```
div.b.mn p{
 margin: 4px 4px 5px 4px; 
}
div.b.mn p a{
 border: 2px dashed #93F;
 background-clip: content-box;
 display:inline-block;
 border-radius: 5px;
}
div.b.mn p a:hover, div.b.mn p a:focus{
 border-color: #F93;
}
```

**[fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/p62Lrhsk/8/)**

Comment: Thanks, this works. But maybe you can give me a tip - how i should keep same distance between elements with such approach? Changing margin value somehow screws all the positioning.

Comment: Hi Markus_13, I have updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/locateganesh/p62Lrhsk/9/ just and try t understand why I have given comments and some extra codes. your layout is little complicated. It could have been little simple.